# "For one's own good" Vs "In one's best interest"

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms, expressions, sentence-choice

I was wondering if in the following sentence:

> - I know you're mad that I won't let you eat candy for dinner, sweetheart, but **it's for your own good**.

we can substitute the bold part for:

> this is in your best interest.

Actually I know the meaning of both idioms, but both mean the same to me; however, I have my doubts whether the same goes to you as native speakers or there is another story there!

PS. in contrary cases we say:

> - It is **not** in your best interest.

Can we say instead:

> - It is **not** for your own good.

Do they make a good sense to you?

Please kindly enlighten me.

Comment: In *British* English we usually pluralise ***interests*** in such contexts, whereas AmE favours the singular.

Comment: Yes FFRM you are exactly right. I found that  out.

Answer (score 1):

- For your own good
- In your best interest

As you say, they mean pretty much the same thing, but they are **not** always interchangeable.

"In your best interest" is more likely to be used for some *action* you carry out on someone's behalf. We speak about "*acting in one's best interest*".

"For your own good" is more likely to be used if you were physically giving someone something - for example, if you gave someone some medication that they didn't want. The medicine itself is *for* their good, although you might say that the *act* of giving it to them was in their interest.

"*Not* in your best interest" is a correct negation of the phrase.

We would not say "it isn't for your own good" - who's good is it for, then? An alternative phrase would be "it would be *to your detriment*", or less formally "*it wouldn't be good for you*".

Comment: Well, If I'm not mistaken, **"this is not in your own good"** and **"This is in your best interest"** are not considered the correct registers of the expressions. Do you confirm @Astralbee?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "this is in your best interest", so long as "this" refers to an action. Like my example of medicine - how can a medicine itself be in someone's interest? But the *act* of giving it someone can be. "Not in your own good" doesn't make sense, as I've said in my answer. If something isn't in my own good, who's good is it for?

Comment: Whether it makes sense or not, "[not] **in** your own good" is not idiomatic in *any* context. But it's perfectly possible to contrive contexts where *not **for** your own good* is a reasonable thing to say: *You're doing this not for your own good, but for the benefit of the community.*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica That's a good point and an interesting use of the idiom, although it is essentially the same as saying "you're not doing this for your own good" and I feel it confuses the point of the question.

Comment: OP's first comment under your question cited that non-idiomatic preposition usage - which you misleadingly dismissed as "not making sense", where actually it's just the "wrong" preposition. I also think it might help OP to be made aware of the not insignificant difference it makes to include the emphatic optional possessive ***own*** in some of the examples.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is the same as far as I am concerned. The register is different: "for your own good" is familiar, "in your best interests" is formal.

Apart from that the usage is slightly different.

> It is not in your best interest

It's okay to use the negative but in the UK we usually pluralise and say, "interests"

**EDIT** Please see the comment by @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica concerning US usage.

---

> It is not for your own good.

We do not usually negate this expression.

We might say, "it's bad for you".

---

Comment: According to your statements @chasly-supports Monica I think "in one's best interest" is usually used in negative form and "for one's own good" is often used in positive form. Hence, instead of saying "it's bad for you" we can say: "it is not in your best interest" although it would be a formal sentence. Do you agree?

Comment: Didn't you used to be "Chasly **from the UK**"? Americans usually use singular ***interest*** in such contexts - it's only BrE that pluralises it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica - Yes. Thanks for the correction. I'll mention it in my answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I'm in the UK and I wouldn't pluralise it. I would see that as a mistake.

Comment: @Astralbee: According to NGrams, in American English, [singular is twice as common as plural.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+his+best+interest%2Cin+his+best+interests&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) But in British English, [plural is at least three times more common than singular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+his+best+interest%2Cin+his+best+interests&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3). Because of unavoidable misclassifications, BrE is usually underrepresented for recent text, so the reality is even *more* skewed.

Comment: That is still vague to me whether despite "it is for your own good" which cannot be negated, the expression "it is in your best interest" can be used in positive form or not. As you mentioned, the expression "in one's best interest" is used in negative form, but I do not know whether I can also use it in positive form. Please someone kindly explain that to me.

Comment: You can use "in your best interest(s)" and you can also use "not in your best interest(s)" The expressions are equally correct although of course they are opposite in intention.